# How to execute facebook app as a Native app on Mobile Facebook App and not on the Mobile Browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, browser, native, facebook-canvas

The question is related to the mobiles.
I need to execute my facebook app not only via browsers but even inside the Facebook application, and I even would like the app to appear on the left list of my Facebook profile apps (I explain this better in the photos attached).

[image]

[image]

I tested many configurations, but nothing worked.

With the current configuration on the mobile I am able to open my facebook app through the browsers only.
In the Facebook native application if I search for the app, I cannot find it, and so even execute it. 
At the moment my Facebook app is not published, it is only in the sandbox and visible only to administrators, developers and testers.

I write down my current configuration, so if you have any idea / clue, let me know.
Thanks in advance.

---

App on Facebook

CANVAS PAGE
https://apps.facebook.com/[NAMESPACE]

Canvas URL
http://[MYWEBSITE]/?canvas=true

Secure Canvas URL
https://[MYWEBSITE]/?canvas=true

---

Website

Site URL
https://apps.facebook.com/[NAMESPACE]

Mobile Site URL
https://www.facebook.com/[MYFACEBOOKPAGE]/app_[MYFACEBOOKAPPID]?ref=ts

---

Page Tab

Page Tab URL
http://[MYWEBSITE]/

Secure Page Tab URL
https://[MYWEBSITE]/

Comment: Do you mean like a native mobile app or really like a native facebook app? Because you can start a mobile app out of facebook if you've installed it in facebook too.

Comment: I mean like an application inside the Facebook application.

Comment: Did you find a document saying that this was possible? I don't think it is

Comment: No @Igy , I did not read anything about it. I was just guessing it was possible to add a Tab Application on my list application.

Comment: So is there a way to put an app in the facebook mobile app bookmarks list even if it opens in the browser?